# Is GEF4 mature enough?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-gef

I am familiar to GEF3. GEF4 has a better architecture.
And I have to make decision whether using GEF3 or GEF4 MVC for our project.

My question is: Currently, is GEF4 mature (e.g full editing features like GEF3, documents, API's stability) enough? Or should I use GEF3 instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would say since the GEF 4.0.0 release that bundled GEF4 1.0.0 the framework is quite stable (API-wise). However, some support for common functionality is still lacking, which you would need to implement yourself (e.g. direct editing). If you are still unsure, you can implement a prototype with GEF to see if it fits. If you run into any problems, the [GEF forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/81/) is a nice place to get help.